# Is university allowed to refuse to confirm my masters theme due to lack of appropriate research staff?

Tags: thesis, advisor

I am paying for my studies and I have chosen my own theme for my MS thesis. It is in artificial general intelligence and symbolic methods, rather rare theme. I am promising to do all the work fully myself, with some guidance by external researchers. Noone in the department is willing to be the advisor for my theme. I consider this research direction to be of utmost importance, in any case it is far more superior than the machine translation themes to some minor language - themes that are proposed by the department. I am not asking the would-be advisor to be expert in the field, I am asking just formal signature on the papers to continue my own research. Can university refuse to give me advisor? Maybe I can ask my money back? Maybe I ask the university to improve its quality and topicality of its research directions?

Comment: Can you edit the title? It isn't true that the university is refusing to confirm, they're unwilling to authorise a certain topic, because it is out of scope.

Comment: I will just try to be nice. I hope that every researcher is open for prospective challenges, ideas, efforts, for gaining new knowledge and insight (even more if those help humanity), that is why they are at the University :).

Comment: @TomR Are you implying that the faculty in your department is not open? They probably are open, but they also have other responsibilities and they thus need to prioritize. A good case can be made for interdisciplinary research, but an equally good case can be made for specialization. I know you are upset that your priorities don't match their priorities, but such is life. This won't be the last time you will have that experience. A productive strategy to deal with those instances won't consist of blaming the others for not sharing your priorities...

Comment: The way you ask the question makes it seem you really don't understand much about research, which would lead me to guess that you really shouldn't be attempting the stated topic. How about you listen to the reasons your professors are giving you for why your topic is not being approved--your professors are almost surely right.

Comment: Do you already have the external researchers agreement to help? If you don't, that could also be a sticking point.

Answer (score 15):

See this from the point of the department: They are giving out diplomas saying "we have seen the work produced by this student and certify that it meets these requirements". If there are no specialists in a given topic, how can they certify that you meet those requirements? When you choose a department for doing your masters then it is up to you to determine that they are doing the things you are interested in. So yes they can and should refuse if they feel they don't have anyone with the expertise necessary to evaluate your work. You can always ask your money back, but in all likelihood they refuse.

You can always ask the university to cover different topics, but universities cannot cover all topics so choices have to made. Adding a topic typically means hiring one or more additional professors. That is a really big long term investment. They are not going to make that investment because a student (who is almost done anyhow) wants that topic.

Comment: Surely the department can evaluate a dissertation even without a specialist?

Comment: @user2768 Just think about the related work section. Without anyone familiar with the research area, how will they be able to tell whether the dissertation omits related work that should have been cited and described?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Researchers rarely no if related work sections are complete, this is typical of peer-review. Whether such knowledge is necessary depends on the grading criteria, which will partly depend on the type of dissertation, e.g., research-only vs. some other deliverable.

Comment: @user2768 It depends on how far removed the topic is from the expertise present in the department. Often disciplines are split up in a large number of sub-sub-sub-sub-disciplines. Some can talk to each other, and between others there is basically no common ground.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I don't disagree, but I'm not sure that's particularly relevant, since taught courses may be _removed...from the expertise present in the department_. This isn't surprising, because teaching material from a textbook isn't particularly difficult.

Comment: @user2768 The OP is not looking for someone to give her or him a course, but is looking for someone to sign off on her/his Master's thesis. A master's thesis is supposed to be quite a bit more than a regurgitated textbook.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I know; the teaching example was only intended to illustrate that academics are capable of operating outside their immediate research area.

Comment: No body should be giving lectures from a text book at a master's level. I definately would demand my money back if the stuff I was being taught on a masters was out of date enough to be in a text book.

Comment: @user2768 IanSudbery is right, and a thesis should be even more current.
Your thesis might take for granted things that readers won't know (tho it shouldn't), and only experts might know what subtle mistakes to watch for.
A master thesis gets close to the frontiers of knowledge, even tho it isn't quite a PhD. To understand "frontiers of knowledge" properly, see http://matt.might.net/articles/phd-school-in-pictures/.

Comment: @IanSudbery Do you have evidence to suggest that _no body [is] giving lectures from a text book at a master's level_? I strongly suspect many are and that standards vary significantly country-to-country. Regardless, my point remains: A master's level course can be taught by a non-expert, in particular, an academic in the broader field, e.g., a computer scientist could teach artificial intelligence.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Non-experts examine PhDs, so surely non-experts can examine master's level work?

Comment: @user2768 No, experts examine PhDs, and non-experts (even sitting on a committee) will rely on experts; for a PhD, “expert” is defined even more restrictively than for a master thesis.
EDIT: re master courses, standards vary; yet, one taught by a non-expert will be significantly worse. My PhD advisor once mentioned this explicitly.

Comment: @Ian Sudbery: *No body should be giving lectures from a text book at a master's level.* --- This is apparently extremely field dependent, as it almost wouldn't occur to me that something at the masters level would be so specialized and new that it wouldn't be in a textbook. Indeed, Springer's [Graduate Texts in Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Texts_in_Mathematics) (280 titles) is one of the best known book series in all of mathematics, and there's also the AMS textbook series [Graduate Studies in Mathematics](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm) (206 titles).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Fair enough — tho would you have a non-expert teach that? (Say, an algebraist teaching analysis, or viceversa?) But I can believe maths has more standard curricula.
OTOH, topics CS for “artificial intelligence” are likely less stable. My field (PL) has some textbooks, but you’d still want a specialist to teach about it.
Finally, even if an expert of A can teach B, it doesn’t follow they can supervise topic X picked by a student. Or in fact, that they accept X as being worthy of study (EDIT: at least by them, and possibly by others).

Comment: I don't understand what the discussion is about: There are degrees to being a non-expert. I am from sociology, and there are many sub-fields in sociology that I can understand even though they are not my thing. There are also many other sub-fields that, even though they are supposedly writing in a language I understand, I don't understand a word they are writing and I don't know what they are trying to achieve. I will happily grade a thesis from a former sub-field but not from a latter sub-field. I cannot see why that is controversial.

Comment: @user2768 - I have no evidence because thats not what I said. I specially said _should_ not _is_. In my dept we don't teach from textbooks beyond first year undergrad. I reckon given enough time, I could teach pretty much everything at first year, and probably about 50% of the second year, but I couldn't teach even a fraction of the third year courses, without effectively doing another degree myself.

Answer (score 4):

Approach an advisor that you already have a relationship with. Explain that you are an excellent student, providing grades as evidence, if that's true. (If it isn't, I wonder whether pursuing this topic can be recommended.) Explain why you are passionate for *artificial general intelligence and symbolic methods*,  why the *research [is] of utmost importance*, and perhaps mention why it is *superior [to] the machine translation themes...proposed by the department* (being careful not to criticise the potential advisor's research domain). Explain that you have found external researchers willing to guide you, providing letters of support as evidence, if those researchers will provide them. You must deliver your message succinctly and coherently.

---

> Can university refuse to give me advisor?

The university aren't refusing: You are refusing to find a topic that the university is willing to supervise.

> Maybe I can ask my money back?

Sure, but you're seemingly at fault, not the university, and I think it is extremely unlikely that you have any chance of getting your money back (at least, not in the context of your question).

> Maybe I ask the university to improve its quality and topicality of its research directions?

Sure, but it won't help you. (Change takes time.)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you should have agreed the “theme” with your advisor for it to be accepted and ratified by the institution.

If you have not, then you might need to choose a different topic.

Comment: The OP doesn't have an advisor, they cannot find one willing to supervise their "theme."

Comment: @user2768 some or many places organise the advisor first, then sort the theme...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That seemingly aligns with my comments (in response to _Maarten Buis_'s answer): Academics can examine work that is outside their expertise. (If that weren't the case, then assigning advisors first wouldn't work, unless advisors have veto rights.) Others disagree with my comments...

Comment: @user2768 No, I did not say that... Many places use the skills or areas of their faculty to control the range of themes possible.

Comment: How does _organis[ing] the advisor first_ then _sort[ing] the theme_ work, if advisors won't supervise certain themes?

Comment: @user2768 because the student discusses the theme with the advisor and **they reach an agreement**. This seems most logical and was how it happens in the several places I have worked...

Comment: I think I get it: There's some pre-selection, whereby you _organise the advisor first_, based upon their themes, then you negotiate more precisely later